# Jetbrains IDEA, How to make IDEA to create new import for each partial class in the same package

Tags: java, intellij-idea

For example, I have class A with such imports:

```
import some.package.Class1
import some.package.Class2
```

When I put reference to some.package.Class3 in my class IDEA turns all inputs into such line of code:

```
import some.package.*
```

How can I make IDEA create new import for each class and do not replace them with '.*'?

Regards, Evgeniy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDE settings -> Code Style -> Java -> select "import" tab.

Change the value of "Class count to import with '*'".

(Note: this is for 12.x, but it should not differ too much for older versions)